How can I correctly read the cloned images of 6 hard disks (4TB each) from a NAS, saved as RAW files?
I have cloned 6 hard disks, each with a capacity of 4TB, from a NAS. The cloning process produced a RAW file for each disk.
I need to access the data contained in these RAW files, and I'm looking for guidance on how to:

Mount or read the RAW files so I can explore the contents of the cloned disks.
Understand if I need to account for the RAID array (if applicable) and how to manage it properly.
Identify which software tools (preferably libre-source) are recommended for handling large files like these and for examining or recovering the data.
Any advice on how to proceed, which tools to use, and potential issues to be aware of would be greatly appreciated.

I had thought of somehow virtualizing the NAS environment by loading the RAW files as if they were physical disks, perhaps using VirtualBox or similar software.
Any advice on how to proceed, which tools to use, and potential issues to be aware of would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Most operating systems support some way of attaching a file as if it were a disk. Linux calls it "loop mounting" or "loop device" (see the losetup command or the gnome-disks GUI), and its software RAID tools can accept such devices as if they were real disks. The size of the files doesn't matter.
If the disks were using ZFS, then FreeBSD's equivalent should be mdconfig or vnconfig and I think Solaris/Illumos has lofiadm.
Windows is trickier as it only supports this for the VirtualPC "VHD" or Hyper-V "VHDX" image formats, not for raw images. QEMU's qemu-img can convert between them, but VirtualBox's vboxmanage convertfromraw might also be able to output a VHD (I think it can, but don't remember offhand). It also won't recognize any RAID that a non-Windows NAS would use.
(Once you have the VHD though, you can attach it to a VirtualBox VM and boot some kind of Linux distribution to examine the disks with – or do the same with QEMU. The latter can directly attach raw images as well.)
As another method, the 7-zip archiver understands disk partition tables and many filesystems – you can just open a disk image like an archive. (There's a large overlap between the two.)

"... and boot some kind of Linux distribution to examine the disks with ..." - download the Ubuntu Desktop install image and use it as boot disk, select "Try ubuntu" -mode at startup (after boot) and then run any commands you'd wish.
